# Puzzle Packing Box Z optimisation

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

### **Explanation**

For this Christmas, I got [this](http://www.creativecrafthouse.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=278) puzzle as a present, with the aim being to try and fill 25 "Z" shaped pieces into a 5x5x5 box. Once I saw this gift, I thought I would challenge myself into trying to make a program to solve this for me.

[image]
*Picture of piece*

All pieces are exactly the same, which are 5 units in size illustrated like the image above. The pieces can be rotated in any fashion you like (besides tilting the pieces on a diagonal) but there are 25 of them to be fitted into this box.

### **What I've done**

The code below will try and find the solution to this puzzle through means of brute force.

*This class encapsulates where a single position of a piece is in a 3D plane where the x, y, and z offsets are 0.*

```
/// <summary>
/// BoxCoordinate represents the coordinates of a single cube in a piece.
/// 
/// All pieces are the same, however, there are 24 different orientations 
/// which must be taken into account (e.g. piece standing up facing north, 
/// laying down to the right facing east, etc.
/// 
/// All coordinates should consider that the end of the piece starts at 
/// x = 0, y = 0, z = 0
/// </summary>
public sealed class BoxCoordinate {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public BoxCoordinate(int x, int y, int z) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

*This class encapsulates every single piece orientation that is possible in this simulation (for example, a piece can be standing up right, laying to the right, rotated clockwise, etc.).*

*The class also provides a multi dimensional array of every single piece combination for each "cell" in the cube.*

```
/// <summary>
/// The Pieces class does two things, it initializes every single piece orientation
/// (e.g. pieces0, pieces1, etc), and allocates what piece orientation is legal for each cell
/// in the box via a 3d array.
/// 
/// In the image link provided, the red cube represents the first cube which is always at 
/// x = 0, y = 0, z = 0
/// </summary>
public sealed class Pieces {

    // http://i.imgur.com/6mFMU5J.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces0 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, 1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(3, 1, 0)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/kme45CF.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces1 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, 0, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(3, 0, 1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/DhF5IYl.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces2 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, -1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(3, -1, 0)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/MG1G66n.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces3 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(2, 0, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(3, 0, -1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/bxnwOIC.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces4 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, 3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/gbiB4eC.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces5 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, 3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/mwCrYT3.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces6 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, 3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/EQmgPGc.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces7 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, 2),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, 3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/cm1vql3.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces8 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, 1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-3, 1, 0)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/2RE1sdz.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces9 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, 0, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(-3, 0, -1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/dvdBLSW.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces10 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, -1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-3, -1, 0)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/qg0BxU7.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces11 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-2, 0, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(-3, 0, 1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/FuHBeRU.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces12 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, -3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/MCg7drH.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces13 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 0, -3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/JXENmMc.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces14 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, -3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/ReC85sL.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces15 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, -2),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 0, -3)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/EOOB6sA.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces16 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 2, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 3, 1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/Vtg4KDF.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces17 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, 3, 0)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/6Txc4Ct.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces18 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 2, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 3, -1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/pCmEBNx.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces19 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, 3, 0)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/AKy1jYX.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces20 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -2, -1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -3, -1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/rRl87QY.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces21 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, -2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(1, -3, 0)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/ZhVYL7D.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces22 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -2, 1),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -3, 1)
    };

    // http://i.imgur.com/fwHi7N6.png
    private static readonly BoxCoordinate[] pieces23 = new BoxCoordinate[] {
        new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -1, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(0, -2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, -2, 0),
        new BoxCoordinate(-1, -3, 0)
    };

    // To store every possible piece orientation for each cell in the box.
    // The first dimension represents z, second y, third x
    public BoxCoordinate[][][] Piece { get; }

    public Pieces() {
        Piece = new BoxCoordinate[][][] {
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 0, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces4, pieces7, pieces16, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 0, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces4, pieces5, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 0, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 0, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces7, pieces8, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 0, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces8, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 1, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces4, pieces6, pieces7, pieces16, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 1, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 1, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 1, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces8, pieces10, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 1, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces8, pieces10, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 2, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces4, pieces6, pieces7 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 2, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 2, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 2, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces8, pieces10, pieces11 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 2, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces8, pieces10, pieces11 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 3, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces4, pieces6, pieces7, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 3, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 3, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 3, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces8, pieces10, pieces11, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 3, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces8, pieces10, pieces11, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 4, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces6, pieces7, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 4, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 4, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 4, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces10, pieces11, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 0, y = 4, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces5, pieces6, pieces10, pieces11, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 0, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces3, pieces4, pieces7, pieces16, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 0, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces3, pieces4, pieces5, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 0, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 0, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces7, pieces8, pieces9, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 0, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces8, pieces9, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 1, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces4, pieces6, pieces7, pieces16, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 1, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 1, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 1, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 1, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 2, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces4, pieces6, pieces7 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 2, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 2, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 2, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 2, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 3, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces4, pieces6, pieces7, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 3, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 3, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 3, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 3, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 4, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces6, pieces7, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 4, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 4, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 4, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces5, pieces6, pieces7, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 1, y = 4, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces5, pieces6, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 0, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces3, pieces16, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 0, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces3, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 0, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 0, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 0, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 1, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces16, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 1, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 1, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 1, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 1, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 2, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 2, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 2, x = 2 
            // - Since this is in the middle of the box, all piece orientations go beyond the box bounds
            // - so no legal pieces can fit
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 2, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 2, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 3, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 3, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 3, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 3, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 3, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 4, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 4, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 4, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 4, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 2, y = 4, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces20, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 0, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces16, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 0, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 0, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 0, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces11, pieces12, pieces13, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 0, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces11, pieces12, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 1, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces16, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 1, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 1, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 1, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 1, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces12, pieces14, pieces15, pieces16, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 2, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 2, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 2, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 2, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 2, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces12, pieces14, pieces15 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 3, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 3, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 3, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 3, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 3, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces12, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 4, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces13, pieces14, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 4, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces1, pieces2, pieces3, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 4, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 4, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces22, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 3, y = 4, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces9, pieces10, pieces11, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces22, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 0, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 0, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 0, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 0, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces12, pieces13, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 0, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces12, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 1, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 1, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 1, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 1, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18, pieces19 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 1, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces12, pieces14, pieces15, pieces17, pieces18 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 2, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 2, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 2, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 2, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 2, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces12, pieces14, pieces15 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 3, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces20, pieces21 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 3, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces0, pieces2, pieces3, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 3, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 3, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces12, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 3, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces8, pieces9, pieces10, pieces12, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces23 },

            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 4, x = 0
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces2, pieces3, pieces13, pieces14, pieces20, pieces21 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 4, x = 1
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces2, pieces3, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 4, x = 2
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 4, x = 3
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces9, pieces10, pieces13, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces21, pieces23 },
            // All piece orientations at - z = 4, y = 4, x = 4
            new BoxCoordinate[][] { pieces9, pieces10, pieces14, pieces15, pieces20, pieces23 }
        };
    }
}
```

*This is the main class where the simulation is. It initialises the Pieces class for use. The main method in this class is the Simulate() method where it loops through the BoxContainer array and determine whether a piece can fit there (the Place() method does the majority of the latter functionality).*

*If it is able to place a piece inside the Box, it will increment a counter indicating the number of pieces on the board and will call the Simulate() method like a recursive call.*

*If it can't find a spot to place a piece, it will call the UnPlace() method where the last piece placed will be removed, and will let the method go back to the previous Simulate() in the stack*

```
/// <summary>
/// This represents the box we are trying to fill with 25 pieces. The box is represented by a 3d array (5x5x5) 
/// all initialized to -1 (NoPiece). The array is 3d so that we can simulate z, y, x coordinates.
/// 
/// The simulation works by iterating over all the cells in the box. It will then check if that particular cell
/// equals NoPiece. If it is true, then it will try and iterate over all the possible orientations for that cell.
/// 
/// If a piece orientation can be fit, then the array indexes at 5 points representing the piece will be set to 
/// CurrentCount, which will be incremented afterwards once the piece is set. After a piece is set, Simulate() will 
/// make a recursive call on itself and repeat the cycle. 
/// 
/// If no piece orientation can fit, then it will continue onto the next cell in the box. 
/// If there is no possible piece which can fit, UnPlace() will be called which removes the last placed piece from the box,
/// and decrements CurrentCount. Once that happens, the program will naturally full back onto the previous stack of Simulate()
/// and try to continue on fitting in pieces from where it left off.
/// 
/// The simulation finishes when CurrentCount equals 25 (NumPieces)
/// 
/// </summary>
public sealed class Box {
    public const int NumPieces = 25;
    public const int PieceSize = 5;
    public const int NoPiece = -1;

    private int highCount;
    private int currentCount;
    private int lowCount;
    private int iter = 0;

    private int[,,] boxContainer;

    private Pieces pieces;

    private BoxCoordinate[] log;

    public Box() {
        pieces = new Pieces();
        boxContainer = new int[PieceSize, PieceSize, PieceSize];

        // Initialize array with NoPiece
        for (int z = 0; z < PieceSize; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < PieceSize; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < PieceSize; x++) {
                    boxContainer[z, y, x] = NoPiece;
                }
            }
        }

        // This is used in Simulate_Two, for keeping track of previous iterations for back tracking
        log = new BoxCoordinate[NumPieces];

        for (int i = 0; i < log.Length; i++) {
            log[i] = new BoxCoordinate(0, 0, 0);
        }

        currentCount = 0;
        highCount = currentCount;
        lowCount = currentCount;           
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will run the simulation of trying to place 25 pieces into a box. This is a recursive solution
    /// and it is my first simulate method I wrote, but after developing Simulate_Two, I'm not sure if this is 
    /// correct. More info on this in Simulate_Two method comment.
    /// </summary>
    public void Simulate() {
        // Iterate through all the cells
        for (int z = 0; z < PieceSize && currentCount < NumPieces; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < PieceSize && currentCount < NumPieces; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < PieceSize && currentCount < NumPieces; x++) {
                    // If cell hasn't been set
                    if (boxContainer[z, y, x] == NoPiece) {
                        // If a piece has been placed
                        if (place(x, y, z, pieces.Piece[(z * NumPieces) + (y * PieceSize) + x])) {
                            // Go and try to fit the next piece
                            update();
                            Simulate();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentCount != NumPieces) {
            unPlace();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is an iterative approach to the simulation. When I ran this, not only was I able to get up to 23 
    /// in currentCount very quickly (never been able to do so in Simulate), but lowCount was able to go lower 
    /// than what Simulate could which has me confused on which one has been implemented correctly.
    /// </summary>
    public void Simulate_Two() {
        bool placed = false;

        while (currentCount < NumPieces) {
            placed = false;
            for (int z = log[currentCount].Z; z < PieceSize && !placed; z++) {
                for (int y = log[currentCount].Y; y < PieceSize && !placed; y++) {
                    for (int x = log[currentCount].X; x < PieceSize && !placed; x++) {
                        if (boxContainer[z, y, x] == NoPiece) {
                            if (place(x, y, z, pieces.Piece[(z * NumPieces) + (y * PieceSize) + x])) {
                                // Go and try to fit the next piece
                                updateLog(x, y, z);

                                placed = true;

                                update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!placed) {
                updateLog(0, 0, 0);
                unPlace();
                log[currentCount].X++;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will print each layer of the box in the console alongside additional 
    /// debugging information like current/high/lowCount. It isn't recommended to call 
    /// this method too frequently as writing to console is an expensive operation
    /// </summary>
    private void print() {
        Console.Write("Current Count: {0}, Highest Count: {1}, Lowest Count: {2}", currentCount, highCount, lowCount);

        for (int z = 0; z < PieceSize; z++) {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int y = 0; y < PieceSize; y++) {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int x = 0; x < PieceSize; x++) {
                    int a = boxContainer[z, y, x];

                    Console.Write("{0}{1} ", a >= 0 && a < 10 ? " " : "", boxContainer[z, y, x]);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will try and place a piece at the specified z/y/z coordinates. If it can, this method
    /// will place the piece at that position and return true, otherwise will return false.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">x value</param>
    /// <param name="y">y value</param>
    /// <param name="z">z value</param>
    /// <param name="collection">Possible pieces that can go into that position</param>
    /// <returns>If a piece can fit at that specified location</returns>
    private bool place(int x, int y, int z, BoxCoordinate[][] collection) {
        foreach (BoxCoordinate[] pieces in collection) {
            // This is so valid never sets to true as no pieces will skip foreach loop
            if (pieces.Length == 0) continue;

            bool valid = true;

            foreach (BoxCoordinate piece in pieces) {
                // If cell has already been set, move onto next piece orientation
                if (boxContainer[piece.Z + z, piece.Y + y, piece.X + x] != NoPiece) {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If found a place for a piece, set that piece equal to CurrentCount, then increment
            if (valid) {
                foreach (BoxCoordinate piece in pieces) {
                    boxContainer[piece.Z + z, piece.Y + y, piece.X + x] = currentCount;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main reason for this method is to update currentCount, but it is also convenient to update 
    /// debugging variables in here as well
    /// </summary>
    private void update() {
        currentCount++;

        // Below can be altered, used for debugging messages
        iter++;

        if (lowCount > currentCount) {
            lowCount = currentCount;
        }

        if (currentCount > highCount) {
            highCount = currentCount;
            print();
            lowCount = currentCount;
        }

        if (iter > 10000000) {
            print();
            iter = 0;
            lowCount = currentCount;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used for getting rid of the last placed piece from the box
    /// </summary>
    private void unPlace() {
        int count = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < PieceSize && count < PieceSize; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < PieceSize && count < PieceSize; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < PieceSize && count < PieceSize; x++) {
                    // If cell equals to latest piece, set to NoPiece
                    if (boxContainer[z, y, x] == currentCount - 1) {
                        boxContainer[z, y, x] = NoPiece;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        currentCount--;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simple wrapper method for updating the log
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">x value</param>
    /// <param name="y">y value</param>
    /// <param name="z">z value</param>
    private void updateLog(int x, int y, int z) {
        log[currentCount].X = x;
        log[currentCount].Y = y;
        log[currentCount].Z = z;
    }


}
```

**Note: there is a function called Print() which prints out all the pieces by number, layer by layer, but have omitted all calls to this method for brevity.**

### **Concerns**

From my testing, I believe everything is running fine however this simulation is running slow being a brute force solution. From a design point of view, could the algorithm be further improved on for performance?

**Note: I've never finished the simulation completely so that might be that it is really slow or there is a design flaw in my code**

### **Edit**

I've added some class comments which should give you a better idea of the flow of the program. I've also supplied links within the `Pieces` class so that you can see what, for example, `pieces0`, `pieces1`, etc looks like. If you need more details, just comment below and I will supply with more information if need be.

### **Edit - 2**

I've updated the code to include a second Simulate method (Simulate_Two) which is based on an iterative approach. This method seems to be behaving differently than the first Simulate (I suspect it is because of the line `log[currentCount].X++;`) in the way that it reaches 23 in currentCount and it actually backtracks further than the first Simulate.

Also, here is a link to the Packing Box Z on GitHub as requested by @OscarGuillamon in the comment section: https://github.com/hquinn/packingboxz

Comment: You never finished the simulation completely, but are you sure it's at least sometimes producing correct results so far?

Comment: @Mast I have inserted the Print() method into the code to update me on what is going on. From what I see, it can fit 21 pieces really quickly, but will take half a minute to fit 22 pieces. Never seen it go over 22, so I can't be sure if there is some sort of flaw in the program or it is slow. The pieces as far as I am concerned look like they are being placed correctly, but I don't want to say that it will work for all cases (I am 99% sure it is right).

Comment: That `Pieces` class is awful to look at.  Isn't there a better way?  And I don't understand what `new BoxPiece[][] { pieces4, pieces5, pieces6, pieces7 }` represents.

Comment: @PierreMenard There is another way to do it, which will get rid of the Piece class entirely, but it will mean having 24 switch case statements in the inner loop of Simulate(). 

How it works is each piece of this puzzle is made up of 5 cubes. So when we make a BoxPiece, that will represent where every single cube can go without any offset applied to it.

Now since the actual box itself is 5x5x5 (125 cubes), there are only a certain amount of combinations that a piece can fit in there.

Comment: @PierreMenard For example: the first initialization (new BoxPiece[][] { pieces0, pieces1, pieces4, pieces7, pieces16, pieces19 }) will be saying that only those pieces can fit in at z = 0, y = 0, x = 0. Essentially, I am pre calculating all the different combinations of how a piece can be rotate at that specific position, which is why I decided to make a Piece class instead of, for example,having switch case statements, because this simulation requires speed. You will notice that in the middle, there is one entry which is empty (very middle cube), which means no piece can fit there.

Comment: @greybeard I've added comments to the code now so that you can understand better. I apologise for not commenting the code before, or for the messy code in the first place, but I wrote this in an hour, and didn't bother with all the styling or trying to make the overall design presentable.

Comment: "Attracting interest to see if someone can think outside the-" I see what you did there. ;D

Comment: @FlagAsSpam We all have to amuse ourselves sometimes.

Comment: Can you post the code on github so I can download it and carry out tests whenever I am able to? It would help me a lot to figure out what needs improvement

Comment: @OscarGuillamon I can add the code to GitHub for sure, not right at this second, but when I have the chance, I'll post it. I've made a version which is iterative instead of recursive, and I think that is faster but not as neat. As for your second question, an end of a piece cannot fit in the direct middle as a piece is 4 segments in length but the middle is 3 segments in. A piece can overlay in the middle, but not start in the middle.

Comment: @OscarGuillamon Is there a way to notify you when I posted it to GitHub?

Comment: If you post here the url or in a modification of your post, I should be able to get a notification, anyways I'll check and give it a look when able

Comment: @OscarGuillamon code has been posted to GitHub, the link is in the post.

Comment: @greybeard instead of a hyperlink?

Comment: Changed in either case

Comment: @Hayden Upon reviewing your code, I find that there are only 24 defined pieces instead of the 25 you stated, am I missing something?

Comment: Also why don't you calculate which pieces fit where, instead of hardcoding which pieces do fit?

Comment: @OscarGuillamon There are 24 piece orientations. It is hard to represent all the rotations of pieces and such, so I made these orientations for ease of use. It doesn't matter if a piece orientation is used more than once, just as long as 25 can fit in there.

Comment: @Hayden Ok, thank you, I was missing that particular thing

Comment: @OscarGuillamon so the exact opposite of what I am doing? Can you enlighten me on how that would make a difference?

Comment: @Hayden I am working on understanding the code and how it works, but basically, what you want to do is, with each piece shape known (the coordinate it's units take), you can iterate the shape through every cell of the 5x5x5 box,  and try to reference the coordinates the shape would take, this will result in some shapes referencing coordinates that are out of bounds, those that give said exception should not be included in the collection of pieces that can be placed in that cell. Did I explain myself alright?

Comment: @OscarGuillamon What I have it at the moment is that each cell can take an array of shapes, which I iterate over each cell and see if a particular shape can still fit there. From my understanding, you want to store all the valid cells within the shape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34916/discussion-between-oscar-guillamon-and-hayden).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer about your algorithm but a couple of performance comments that wouldn't fit in the ongoing comment discussion.

I'm guessing that your deeply nested loops are taking up the bulk of the processing time, so optimizing them should help.

- Have you tried using jagged arrays instead of multidimensional arrays?  Jagged arrays are [faster for storage and retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays).
- I see that you have calculations like `(z * NumPieces)` in your inner-most loops.  You can calculate that just after the `for (int z = 0...` loop and cache the value.  You can possibly skip the multiplication entirely by incrementing a counter like this, but you might not see as much of a performance improvement:

  for (int z = 0, zNumPieces; z < PieceSize && currentCount < NumPieces; z++, zNumPieces += NumPieces)
- You can do the same for your `(y * PieceSize)` calculation.
- Your `place(...)` method is called in your inner-most loop, so any optimization there should help.  Use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop.  [They're faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach).
- <strike>Also in `place()`, remove all of your calculations and instead pass in their results as parameters.  This array access `boxContainer[piece.Z + z, piece.Y + y, piece.X + x]` is 6 loops deep but the additions can be calculated at the second, third, and fourth loops respectively.  I don't know if the compiler optimizes this for you.</strike>
- Your `print()` method is in there too (though I suspect not called that often), so optimize it.  Instead of Console.Writing several small strings, piece them together in a StringBuilder and output that at the end of your `print()` method.  Better yet, keep all of your strings in memory and print them out at the very end of your program.

Again, I'm not commenting on your algorithm, just pointing out some issues.  Your loops nest so deeply that you really should focus on making the deepest loops as efficient as possible.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, besides point 5 (which I need further clarification), I've considered all these points but haven't implemented due to laziness or fear it would make things too messy (it already is anyway :P) so I will make these optimisations. Would you perhaps know of any way C# can vectorise this program as I am unfamiliar with it in C#?

Comment: @Hayden, oops, actually I was wrong about point #5.  I'll cross it off.  As for vectorization, I'm not familiar with your algorithm to be sure.  Check out the Task Parallel Library for parallel processing.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx  If you can break your code into independent tasks, you can easily parallelize your code and get it running faster.  Supposing you want 5 threads going at a time, give each possible configuration a unique id, and then have Thread N check each Configuration N % 5.  You'd have to rearrange your code some to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it is hard to think of ways on how to use parallel programming for this simulation, so I will have to look more into it.

Comment: Interesting fact, I tried using a for loop in the `place()` method, and it actually performs slower.

Comment: I am guessing it is because it is faster to access an object than an array index.

Comment: @Hayden, that is interesting.  A foreach loop is syntactic sugar for a code that involves a couple of method calls.  A for loop is much simpler by comparison (though it requires collections to expose their internals).  If you're curious, this page shows code that is equivalent to a foreach loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982/how-do-foreach-loops-work-in-c

Comment: I remember reading that link a while ago. I'll try and retest a for loop approach, but I think that the foreach has better read performance or something.